# clojure  hierarchical diff of two xml files

Tags: xml, clojure, diff

I'm trying to hierarcial diff two small xml files. Clojure.data/diff is gets me close:

```
(clojure.data/diff (clojure.xml/parse "file1.xml") (clojure.xml/parse "file2.xml"))
```

clojure.data/diff will return the before and after, but it does not maintain the xml structure (no :tag elements) and the before and after cannot easily be converted to xml (such as using clojure.xml/emit).

How can I do a hierarchical diff on two xml files in clojure?

Answer (score 2):

[XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) has stand-alone methods for diffing XML. You can include the library and just call it from within Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like an enhancement request in clojure.data. Could you please open an issue on the jira page.

http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ

even better if it includes a patch (sign the contrib agreement first)

Comment: I'm not sure it is a bug, clojure.data/diff just does not fix exactly what I am trying to do with xml files.  It correctly tells me what the differences are but it does maintain a structure that can easily be converted to xml. The :tag key does not appear in the differences when both files have it - it only ends up in the last item in the tuple. This is technically correct, but for me I lose info about the xml structure, specifically the tag names.

Comment: sorry about that I had assumed that the :tags where being dropped and not being diffed correctly. So this would be more like an enhancement request.

Comment: ya, I'm still thinking about how to approach it.. my goal here is to do a hierarchical diff on 2 xml files to determine exactly what was removed, added, or updated (along with where in the tree).